# reset HEAD или чего от меня хочет git?

Tags: git

Что такое

```
Changes to be committed: 
    (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)!!!
```

Чего он от меня хочет???

Comment: Ничего не хочет. Это стандартное сообщение.

Comment: @Эникейщик так делать не чего не нужно? Тогда зачем он это пишет? Ни ради прикола же!

Comment: Информирует....